# ADO.NET vs ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

What is faster - ADO.NET or ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is faster than an ADO.NET datareader.
Entity framework also uses this in "the basement".

However entitity framework helps you to map from database to objects..
With ADO.NET you have to do that yourself.
It depends on how you program it how fast it is..

When you use ADO.NET datatables as "objects". They are a bit slower and memory hungry than plain objects..

Comment: "When you use ADO.NET datatables as "objects". They are a bit slower and memory hungry than plain objects.." - does it mean that ado.net is faster?

Comment: On the other hand, you could argue that working with EF, the programmer is faster than when he has to deal with data readers and other low-level elements....

Comment: What is about the speed web application?

Comment: web or desktop doesn't matter. EF = datareader + object mapper, ADO.NET datatables = datareader + "object" mapper. ADO.NET datareader faster than EF, EF most probably faster than ADO.NET datatables..

Comment: And now comes the `Dapper`, nuff said.

Answer (score 2):

As Julian de Wit says nothing is faster than ADO.NET DataReaders.
ADO.NET Entity Framework is a wrapper to the old ADO.NET.
It is pure Provider independent, ORM and EDL System.
It gives us a lot of benefits that we have had to hand craft or "copy & paste" in the past.

Another benefit that comes with it is that is completely Provider independent.
Even if you like the old ADO.NET mechanism or you are a dinosaur like me(:P) you can use the Entity Framework using the `EntityClient` like `SqlClient`, `MySqlClient` and use the power of Entity-Sql witch is provider independent.
I Know that with ADO.NET you can write a data access Layer and the `DataReaders` etc can be "independent" but you have steal have Queries that are provider specific.

On the other hand,in an enterprise application you may never want to change the data provider.
But as the technology grows, always new needs arise and you may want have to alter the database schema.

When it happens with the old ADO.NET Framework we have to refactor alot of code which is less than maintainable, no matter how we reuse the code.

The performance will be affected but with all these cache technologies out there we can overcome this.

As i always say, "The C is fast, the Assembly even more...but we use C#/VB.NET/Java"